# Can I use superAgent with react-native

Tags: ajax, react-native

I have recently started with react native. Web app is already under development. Web devs are using superagent for Ajax calls, we want to reuse most of web app code, so I was wondering if I could use superagent with react-native. I did little search and came across some github posts from 2015. https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/370. Can anyone share experience with supreagent and react-native combination